# Jenkins concurrent builds archive artifacts

Tags: jenkins, java.util.concurrent

When I trigger concurrent builds in jenkins, only the later finishing build artifacts not archiving.

It says,

Archiving artifacts
‘workspace-2/results*/’ doesn’t match anything, but ‘’ does. Perhaps that’s what you mean?
ERROR: Step ‘Archive the artifacts’ failed: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "workspace-2/results*/, workspace-2/results*/". Configuration error?

But when I checked my slave node for artifacts, it's there.

Run 2 concurrent builds and only first one save artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

Each concurrently executed build occurs in its own build workspace, isolated from any other builds. By default, Jenkins appends "@" to the workspace directory name, e.g. "@2".